# Swift Xib subview not filling view

Tags: swift

I am attempting to present a subview (from a xib) into a view. The subview presents into the view however it does not fill the view as expected, Why is the subview not occupying the frame of the imageControllerPlaceHolder?

```
 var imageScrollerSubView: UIView?

     override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            imageScrollerSubView = UINib(nibName: "ImageScroller", bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil)[0] as? UIView
            imageScrollerSubView?.frame.size.height = ImageScrollerPlaceHolder.frame.size.height
            imageScrollerSubView?.frame.size.width = ImageScrollerPlaceHolder.frame.size.width
            ImageScrollerPlaceHolder.addSubview(imageScrollerSubView!)


        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to update your target view frame in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        imageScrollerSubView?.frame.size.height = ImageScrollerPlaceHolder.frame.size.height
        imageScrollerSubView?.frame.size.width = ImageScrollerPlaceHolder.frame.size.width
}
```